# wp e-commerce emails not working

Tags: wordpress, email, e-commerce

I have seen many questions regarding emails not being sent but so far they haven't been helpful to me. I've been trying to test purchases on my site. After checkout, the order appears in the sales log as "order received". From what I understand when I change it from "order received" to "accepted payment", an email should be sent. Thing is, an email is never sent to the administrator or the customer. I have the store admin email filled out. The digital product is supposed to be sent in the email but the email is not being sent. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I check first dealing with WP emails is to see if the emails wordpress is sending out are being caught in spam, or just being blocked by your email provider, since the WP_Mail() function isn't verified by an email server.

Try [WP-SMTP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/) and do some testing.

Comment: Thanks you made me realize the emails were probably just being blocked or something and that it wasn't the plugins fault. I realized it wasn't working because I was trying to send the emails from local host.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and, for me, the solution was going into cPanel and changing my MX records. They were set up years ago to point to a different server and I found out that I could send but not receive emails. I deleted them and created a new mail.domain.com MX record. That was my issue, may or may not be yours.